# Udp server from boost not working on multithreading, but work only on the main thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, udp, boost-asio

I got a async udp server with boost::asio
but the problem is:
if I launch it on a thread, the server won't work
but if I launch it on the main thread (blocking with the service) it's working...

I've try to do it with a fork but not working eiser

```
class Server {
private:
    boost::asio::io_service _IO_service;
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket> _My_socket;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint _His_endpoint;
    boost::array<char, 1000> _My_Buffer;

private:

    void Handle_send(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t size, std::string msg) {
    //do stuff
   };

    void start_send(std::string msg) {
        _My_socket->async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(msg), _His_endpoint,
            boost::bind(&Server::Handle_send, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred, msg));
    };

    void Handle_receive(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t size) {
    //do stuff
    };

    void start_receive(void) {
        _My_socket->async_receive_from(
            boost::asio::buffer(_My_Buffer), _His_endpoint,
            boost::bind(&Server::Handle_receive, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }

public:
    Server(int port):
    _IO_service(),
    _My_socket(boost::make_shared<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket>(_IO_service, \
        boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(), port)))
    {
        start_receive();
    };

    void Launch() {
        _IO_service.run();
    };
};
```

the objective is to call the Server::Launch in the background.

Comment: You should show the code how `Launch` is called inside main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have undefined behaviour in `start_send`.

`async_send_to` returns immediately, so `msg` as local variable is destroyed when `start_send` returns. When you call `async_send_to` you must ensure that `msg` is not destroyed before asynchronous operation is completed. What is described [in documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/async_send_to/overload1.html) -

> Although the buffers object may be copied as necessary, ownership of
>   the underlying memory blocks is retained by the caller, **which must**
>   **guarantee that they remain valid until the handler is called**.

You can resolve it by many ways, the easiest is to use string as data members (as buffer for sending data):

```
class Server {
    //..
    std::string _M_toSendBuffer;
    // 
    void start_send(std::string msg) {
        _M_toSend = msg; // store msg into buffer for sending
        _My_socket->async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(_M_toSend), _His_endpoint,
            boost::bind(&Server::Handle_send, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred, 
                _M_toSend));
    };
```

Another solution is to wrap `msg` into smart pointer to extend its lifetime:

```
void Handle_send(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t size, 
        boost::shared_ptr<std::string> msg) {
   //do stuff
};

void start_send(std::string msg) {
    boost::shared_ptr<std::string> msg2 = boost::make_shared<std::string>(msg); // [1]
    _My_socket->async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(*msg2), _His_endpoint,
        boost::bind(&Server::Handle_send, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred, 
            msg2)); // [2]
};
```

in [1] line we create `shared_ptr` which taks `msg` content, then in [2] line reference counter of `shared_ptr` is increased when `bind` is called, so string lifetime is extended and it is destroyed after handler is called.

---

Regarding your not-working verion based on thread. You didn't show the code where `Launch` is called, but maybe you just don't join this thread?

```
Server s(3456);
boost::thread th(&Server::Launch,&s);
th.join(); // are you calling this line?
```

or perhaps your code doesn't work by UB in `start_send`.

Comment: firt of all, thanks for you'r answer. I correct the sender probleme. But for the thread, i was using th.detech(); or if (fork() == 0) but never th.join()... with th.join() it's seems to work but it's blocking, but a least it work well. With .join() i need to do main main programme in a other thread and call join() at the same time?

Comment: so a go a bit ahead, and the probleme come from a strdup in the server wich cause the thread to crash if a client connect... and juste after the server is detach, it's connect to himself... the strdup make the thread to crash, so the client cannot connect...

Comment: You say that `th.join()` is blocking, but it depends on where it is called. You must have some waiting condition in `main` function which prevents `main` from returning. Ok, you could call `detach`, but then `main` ends immediately. Before return 0 in main you must block your program, for example by `join` or by using infinite loop with sleeping inside, or whatever else but it must block. Regarding the second comment, I don't get the problem with `strdup`.